# Calculate time taken between dates according to user name

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I got a table where all the data saved. 
I hope it done in SQL.

Now, I want to calculate:

- a) Calculate the gap between "CreationDate" and "CloseDate" (in
  days).
- b) Calculate the gap between "CreationDate" and "ResponseTime"    (in
  hours).

PS: The calculation have to base on working days(Saturday and Sunday not include) and according to userID.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXbuC.png)

C# also acceptable

Comment: show us your efforts until now

Answer (score 1):

To remove *Saturday* and *Sunday* use [DayOfWeek](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

```
DAYOFWEEK(your_date) <> 1 AND DAYOFWEEK(your_date)<>7
```

Use [DateDiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to find the number of days between two dates:

```
datediff(date1,date2)
```

Use [Time_To_Sec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [Timediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) to find the number of hours between two dates:

```
select time_to_sec(timediff(date1, date2 )) / 3600;
```

Answer (score 1):

for getting number of days between CreationDate and CloseDate

```
select DATEDIFF(d, CreationDate, CloseDate)
```

for getting number of Hours between CreationDate and ResponseTime

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, CreationDate , Cast(ResponseTime as datetime))
```